# Как было правильно: расписание или росписание?

Tags: орфография, история

Как было правильно в XIX веке: расписание или росписание (уроков)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Расписанїе** Вот выдержка из Я. К. Грота (11-е изд. 1895 г.):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правда надо учитывать, что орфография и пунктуация XIX в. была в процессе становления и потому упорядочена меньше чем современная. Общепринятое написание отдельных слов может отличаться в зависимости от времени написания и редактора. Так, например, словарь Даля изначально издавался с названием "... жив**а**го великорускаго языка", а с 3-го изд. (1903 г.) он стал называться "... жив**о**го великорусскаго языка...".

Если вас интересует дореформенная орфография, то правила Я. К. Грота можно скачать по [ссылке](http://www.bogoslov.ru/biblio/text/30053/index.html).